# After I login I cannot use the Browser's back button to get back to the point before login

Tags: discussion, bug, login

### Problem

After I login I cannot use the Browser's back button to get back to the point before login.

### Use Case

1. I see an interesting question and want to answer it
2. I login
3. I cannot get back to that question, because Stack Exhange overrides
      the "back" functionality of my browser.

### Opinion

This is very bad UX and Accessibiltiy. It is my strong opinion that this behaviour should be changed. Web sites should never take control of a user's browser. It is very bad practice.

Comment: What browser are you using? I've never experienced that, back button works fine.

Comment: What kind of id provider are you using?

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit) + Firefox 33. StackExchange Provider.